# Multiple outputs based on each if statement being true. Java

Tags: java, if-statement

I am trying to make both of these if statements output if true.

Like if I am enter:

```
cat
car
```

I want it to output:

```
Cat and Car are both the same length. 
Cat and Car both start with C.
```

Right now I am only getting the First output

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;  // Import the Scanner class


public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("input words");

        String myObj, myObj1;

         Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);  // Create a Scanner object
         myObj = sc.nextLine();  // String Input
         myObj1 = sc.nextLine(); // String Input


         if(myObj.length() == myObj1.length()){  // System check for String Length
             System.out.println( myObj + " and " + myObj1 + " are the 
            same length.");

         }
         if ((myObj1.charAt(0) == 'C') && (myObj.charAt(0) == 'C')){

            System.out.println(myObj + " and " + myObj1 + " start with C." );
            } // Output if both start with C
```

Comment: After `myObj = sc.nextLine();  // String Input
         myObj1 = sc.nextLine(); // String Input
` please print out the values

Comment: Unable to reproduce. I get both. --- So does [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/lpu14X).

Comment: works for me `input words
Car
Cat
Car and Cat are the same length.
Car and Cat start with C.`

Comment: BTW `c` does not equal `C`

Comment: @ScaryWombat Oh right, if OP enters `cat`, not `Cat`, then the second output will not show. Nicely spotted, Mr. Wombat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if ((myObj1.charAt(0) == 'C') && (myObj.charAt(0) == 'C')){`

will not be true for the input `car` ot `cat` as

`c` does not equal `C`

After reading the values add this code

```
myObj = myObj.toUpperCase();
myObj1 = myObj1.toUpperCase();
```